# Is the Laplacian an unbounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

"The Laplacian is an unbounded operator": I read this in a book. But on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Examples) it says:

> The Laplace operator $$\Delta:H^2({\mathbb R}^n)\to L^2({\mathbb R}^n)
> \,$$ (its domain is a Sobolev space and it takes values in a space of
>   square integrable functions) is bounded.

Comment: Whether it's bounded or unbounded depends on what topologies you choose. When you endow the domain $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the subspace topology induced by $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the operator is unbounded.

Comment: What is $H^2(\mathbb R^n)$?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the sake of this question having an answer ...

*Functions come with domains*. Often we forget this, as the domain is fixed. In functional analysis, however, half the battle and much of the art is *finding the correct domain.*

The Laplacian on a domain $\Omega$ is ordinarily defined as mapping some linear set of smooth functions into $L^2(\Omega)$. Boundedness/unboundedness is a statement about how the operator relates to a norm. When we regard the domain as a subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$, thereby endowing it with the $L^2$ norm, then the Laplacian is an *unbounded* operator.

When we regard the domain as a subspace of $H^2(\Omega)$, however, endowing it with the $H^2$ norm, the Laplacian is a *bounded* operator.

Some intuition. The $L^2$ norm doesn't know anything about how smooth a function is; when the Laplacian is applied to a function, it can "uncover" hidden "roughness." However the $H^2$ norm *does* take into account how smooth the function is --- a function with very large second derivatives may have a small $L^2$ norm, but will have a very large $H^2$ norm.

So while the Laplacian may uncover hidden roughness in the $L^2$ norm, and so take small vectors and arbitrarily lengthen them, those vectors are already very long in the $H^2$ norm, and so the Laplacian is bounded.