# Action of an operator-valued function of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ and its unboundedness

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, unbounded-operators

I am currently dealing with an operator-valued function
$f(\hat{T})$ of the following kind:
$$f(\hat{T}) =\sqrt{1 + b\hat{T}^2} $$
where $b$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\hat{T}$ is a linear operator acting on the usual Hilbert space of quantum mechanics, i.e. $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
What I am interested in is to define its action on a generic physical state $|\Psi\rangle$ in the representation of its own eigenbasis (of course I am supposing that this exists).

If I am correct, I could proceed with a series expansion of the previous operator.
This leads me to write:
$$\sqrt{1 + b\hat{T}^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n (b\hat{T}^2)^n $$
where $c_n$ is the proper generalized binomial coefficent and the series should converge for $\left\|b\hat{T}^2\right\|\leq 1$.

This should not be a problem in principle, nevertheless, it turns out that, in my framework, the operator $\hat{T}$ is the usual momentum operator of quantum mechanics $\hat{p}$, which - to my knowledge - is unbounded with respect its domain of definition (which should be a dense subset of the Hilbert space  $L^2(\mathbb{R})$).
From this, I deduce that the previous procedure is not suitable for the present case.
Hence what can be done? My question can be exposed from two different points of view:

1)How can I find the action of this operator if the series expansion fails to be a proper instrument?

2)Is it possible to "impose" that the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ be bounded - like some kind of constraint, which I imagine could lead to a redefinition of the operator itself? From a mathematical and physical point of view is this even possible?

Thank you all in advance and sorry for my possible lack of mathematical rigour.

Comment: Have you tried working in the Fourier transformed space, where $T$ is a multiplication operator?

Comment: Can you clarify this? I have tried to work in p-representation (concerning the momentum operator $\hat{p}$), where $\hat{p}$ acts as a multiplication operator if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to "impose" that the momentum operator ̂  be bounded - like some kind of constraint, which I imagine could lead to a redefinition of the operator itself?

Having such a property satisfied indeed requires a redefinition of the operator. This can be done by carefully choosing the domain of the operator. For example, take: $\hat{T}^2 : H^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e., define the domain of this operator to be $H^{2} (\mathbb{R})$, a Sobolev space containing functions that are $L^2$ together with their weak derivatives up to second order. In such a case, $\hat{T}^{2}$ can be shown to be a bounded operator since the Laplacian is bounded, see, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358255/is-the-laplacian-an-unbounded-operator). Note that it's common to define Hamiltonians on $H^2$ in quantum mechanics, see, e.g., from Quantum to Classical Molecular Dynamics by Christian Lubich.

Comment: Thank you, you gave me something to think about and I am sure it will help.
One more thing that I'd like to ask you: roughly speaking, is it correct to state that the boundedness of an operator always implies an upper bound of its eigenvalues spectrum?

Comment: The spectrum of a bounded operator on a Banach space is bounded in $\mathbb{C}$, see, e.g., https://www.impan.pl/~pmh/teach/algebra/additional/spectrum.pdf